# Custom 403 ErrorDocument on LiteSpeed

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using a whitelist on IP's, and as such I'd like to inform the user why this is so.

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 24.11.95.152
```

My IP whitelist in HTACCESS ^

Now, I set the ErrorDocument to /403

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403
```

and finally I rewrite /403 to uhoh.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^403/?$ uhoh.php [NC]
```

However, I still get the typical error from LiteSpeed.

Comment: Done ;) hope it went all well for u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ErrorDocument` directly with the file you wish to use for custom message.

In your case would look like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /uhoh.php
```

From your example, it looks like you're trying to double redirect the error page which is not really needed.